# How Cleanup any non alphanumeric characters before comparing the string?

Tags: php, mysql, regex, duplicates

I have used this function to check user ID to avoid duplication, this is the code :

```
    <?php 
    require_once('includes/config.php');
    if(isset($_GET['Uid'])){
    $Uid = $_GET['UID'];
    $Uid = preg_replace('/^.*?(AP[0-9]{1,}).*?$/i', '$1', $Uid );

        $query = "SELECT user_id FROM user  where user_id='$Uid'";
                $users = mysqli_query($link, $query);
                $result = mysqli_num_rows($users);
    if($result > 0) 
    {   
       echo "Username is already taken, or invalid username!";
    }
    else {
        echo '';
    }
}
?>
```

what I want is that , accepting first 2 letter as AP and the rest 8 Numbers like this one

> AP14000001

and then checking the user ID for duplication if user ID duplicated it gives warning or it accepts it as a new ID

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Would you elaborate more? What's the issue here!?

Comment: Dear @revo I have build a academic portal , there is only one Admin that he controls whole the portal. In user registration part admin registers each teacher with his academic ID which is start with this **AP14000001, AP14000002, AP14000003, ....** 
what I want is that when admin registers new user with his ID the system checks is this ID is valid 10 digits as written above and checks it for duplication ?

Comment: Jay Blanchard solution is what you want?

Comment: what is this exactly means **/^AP[0-9]{1,8}$/**?? @revo

Comment: Means input must start with `AP` following by maximum 8 numbers which is at the end of input.

Comment: Thank you so much dear, and what is the difference between and Mr.Jay's answer and this one :  `$Uid = preg_replace('/^.*?(AP[0-9]{1,}).*?$/i', '$1', $Uid );` @revo

Comment: Actually don't differ in results. Both take an input and extract the ID part and that's what I asked 'Would you elaborate?' Your codes should work too.

Answer (score 1):

The regex for that would be (tested at http://regexpal.com) -

```
/^AP[0-9]{1,8}$/
```

Comment: You forgot about `m` flag

Comment: I don't know why it would need multi-line if it is a user id @revo